# Making navigation Bar's items html

Tags: html, css, html-lists, navigationbar

I'm gonna to create a navigation bar using`<nav> </nav>`. but I don't know that should I use `<Li></Li>` and  in it to make the items, or`<a></a>`is just fine?? and what is the difference between this two?? and which one is better?

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Buy">Buy</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

or

```
<nav>
 <a href="#home">Home</a>
 <a href="#About">About</a>
 <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
 <a href="#Buy">Buy</a>   </nav>
```

Comment: Semantically speaking, the first one is better as it more clearly shows what the element is, i.e. a list (that is what the `ul` tag is btw, see more here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)

Comment: ul and li handles your layout, <a doesnt

Comment: You should generally use <ul> for most things that are an actual list of items. You can control the layout with CSS whether you use a list or not, but in this case, the proper semantic use of HTML asks for a <ul>. In addition to being a common pattern for menu structures, it is also an accessibility requirement, you can read more about it here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/structure/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both of them, it depends of the result that you want to get. The tag `ul` its used for the creation of "unordered lists", which format by default the `li` tags inside it. One of the main differences that I think that you might be searching for, is that if you apply the `display: flex;` to the  element, making the `li` elements show up one behind the other. Here I let you an example of how I apply it:

```
<div>
            <ul style="display=flex;">
                <li>
                    <a href="xxx"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="xxx"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="xxx"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Check https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp for a more visual examples.

Answer (score 0):

Both are ok if you do what you realy need to do, but as the partner says, semantically speaking, the first one is the correct option, the browser and the users will thank you if you choose this option :).

This link is a good reference for a correct use of the semantic html and all its tags:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Answer (score 0):

[image: Output]

**A navigation bar is one of the main components of a website, in my opinion the most important one, it is in fact the first section that the user sees when he/she enter a website and it links to the other main parts.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><body>

<div class="w3-container">
  
  <div class="w3-bar w3-black">
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile w3-green">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">About</a>
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">Services</a>
    <div class="w3-dropdown-hover w3-mobile">
      <button class="w3-button">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
      <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-dark-grey">
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">India</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">USA</a>
        <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-mobile">UK</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```